# Drop down navigation bar that shows results from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have spent forever looking for an example of comprehensive code that will display a "dynamic" navigation bar, showing MySQL entries as options to link to pages. The goal/outline of this specific component of my website is described below:

Add Scores (Nav bar that I wish to add a drop down to)

> Drop down options display Team Names that have been added to a MySQL table named "teams" in my database "Final_Project" (I've omitted username and PW).

User clicks on Team Name and then is redirected to a page where they can edit and submit scores.

So far, I have only found pieces of code...and have inadvertently created a drop down within a drop down. The code is below and is all included for the time being in my "headers" php file where all other nav bar code is housed. The drop down currently doesn't link to anything - but that is a secondary problem that I will tackle after I get the drop down to display correctly.

HELP! PLEASE!

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Add Scores
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <?php
                $username= "omitted";
                $password="omitted";
                $team_name=null;
                try {
                    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:localhost=;dbname=Final_Project', $username, $password);
                    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT team_name FROM teams');
                    $sth->execute(array($team_name));
                    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

                  if ( count($result) ) { 
                    print '<select id="team_name">';
                        foreach ($result as $row) {
                        print '<option value="'.$row['team_name'].'">'.$row['team_name'].'</option>';
                        }
                    print '</select>';
                    print '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';   
                  } else {
                    echo "No rows returned.";
                  }[enter image description here][1]
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }
                ?>
          </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: USE "echo" instead of "print"